# Admin rights required to access serial connection

Tags: active-directory, windows-server-2012-r2, windows-server

I'm just getting started with Active Directory and stuff and created a WS2012R2 domain controller and created a new user with admin right.
However it seems that now I can't access the serial connection on the server unless I right-click on the application and say "Run as Administrator" (Doesn't matter which application, checked Putty and MobaXterm, same issue).
I don't understand why I have to explicitly have to run it as Admin even tough the user is in the Administrator Group. And I also don't understand WHY I need admin rights to access the serial port anyway.
Any help would be appreciated.